# Is there a way to store pixels?

Tags: starbound

You lose 10% of your pixels every time you die. Is there anyway to put your pixels away so that when you die you don't lose as many?

Comment: called the pixel compressor. You need the architect's table, which is the upgraded engineer's table. You need durasteel and gold for it, so it's a fairly low-tier item.